# Why does the custom panel not refreshing automatically

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, gridpanel

I have written a custom panel. Here is the code:

```
public class GameBoardPanel:Panel
{
    public GameBoardPanel() { }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SquareSideLengthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SquareSideLength", typeof(int), typeof(GameBoardPanel), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public int SquareSideLength
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(SquareSideLengthProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(SquareSideLengthProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RowsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Rows", typeof(int), typeof(GameBoardPanel), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public int Rows
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(RowsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RowsProperty, value); }
    }

    public int Columns
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ColumnsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Columns", typeof(int), typeof(GameBoardPanel), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RowProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Row", typeof(int), typeof(GameBoardPanel));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Column", typeof(int), typeof(GameBoardPanel));

    public static void SetRow(DependencyObject control, int value)
    {
        control.SetValue(RowProperty, value);
    }
    public static int GetRow(DependencyObject control)
    {
        return (int)control.GetValue(RowProperty);
    }
    public static void SetColumn(DependencyObject control, int value)
    {
        control.SetValue(ColumnProperty, value);
    }
    public static int GetColumn(DependencyObject control)
    {
        return (int)control.GetValue(ColumnProperty);
    }
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        double min=Math.Min(availableSize.Width/Columns,availableSize.Height/Rows );
        SquareSideLength=(int)min;
        return new Size(SquareSideLength*Columns, SquareSideLength*Rows);
    }
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        double min=Math.Min(finalSize.Width/Columns,finalSize.Height/Rows );
        SquareSideLength=(int)min;
        Size destinationSize = new Size(SquareSideLength * Columns, SquareSideLength * Rows);
        foreach (UIElement element in base.InternalChildren)
        {
            int row = GameBoardPanel.GetRow(element);
            int column = GameBoardPanel.GetColumn(element);
            element.Arrange(new Rect(column * SquareSideLength, row * SquareSideLength,SquareSideLength, SquareSideLength));
        }
        return destinationSize;
    }
}
```

It is very simple idea, similar to wpf `Grid` panel. I have a control which arrange its children on such a panel by setting children `GameBoardPanel.Row` and `GameBoardPanel.Column` attached properties. Let's assume that I have also a `GameObject` class which is a `CustomControl` and I added it to the panel. I want to move it for example to the left. So I do it in the following way:

```
GameObject movable=new GameObject();
//setting properties such as GameBoardPanel.Row and GameBoardPanel.Column
panel.Children.Add(movable);
GameBoardPanel.SetColumn(GameBoardPanel.GetColumn(movable)-1);
```

Let's skip the problem that the `movable` object can move outside the panel. It's not a big problem. However if I did the movement in that way I didn't see any effect. Only after adding an additional line:

```
panel.InvalidateArrange();
```

I observed that the object moved left. I'm quite sure, that if I would do the same with the wpf `Grid`, it's not necessary to call InvalidateArrange method. So, I am curious why does this happen? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set appropriate property metadata options to tell the framework that the `Row` and `Column` attached properties affect the layout of your custom panel:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty RowProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Row", typeof(int), typeof(GameBoardPanel),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentArrange));

public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Column", typeof(int), typeof(GameBoardPanel),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentArrange));
```

---

That said, you should usually also measure the child elements in the MeasureOverride method:

```
protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
{
    double min = Math.Min(availableSize.Width / Columns, availableSize.Height / Rows);
    SquareSideLength = (int)min;

    foreach (UIElement element in InternalChildren)
    {
        element.Measure(new Size(SquareSideLength, SquareSideLength));
    }

    return new Size(SquareSideLength * Columns, SquareSideLength * Rows);
}
```

Moreover it also doesn't seem to be necessary that `SquareSideLength` is a dependency property. It could as well be an ordinary CLR property (or probably just a private field). Its type may also better be `double` instead of `int`.

Finally, your MeasureOverride implementation should also be prepared for an infinite `availableSize` parameter value. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The available size that this
>   element can give to child elements. Infinity can be specified as a
>   value to indicate that the element will size to whatever content is
>   available.

Comment: It works fine. Thank you. I wouldn't get it without your help :P